# Kohana SQL Prepared Statement Safety

Tags: php, mysql, kohana, prepared-statement

On the [Kohana prepared statement documentation](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/database/query/prepared) it states

> Although all parameters are escaped to prevent SQL injection, it is still a good idea to validate/sanitize your input.

From what I read on prepared statements, I was under the impression that binding parameters prevented SQL injection. If this is not the case, what sanitization/escaping method should I be using before binding the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think when they say "it is still a good idea to validate/sanitize", they mean to use Valid class or/and Validation class... To make sure you get the right data inserted in your DB.

More info on Validation in Kohana: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/security/validation

UPDATE:

You should also look into XSS: http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/kohana/security/xss

Comment: agreed, for example what happens if you are inserting an integer and you receive a text string instead. you would probably end up with a 0 in the database instead of what you were expecting.

Comment: So just to be clear, the reason it says that is not because of security concerns, it's just to make sure the data types you're expecting are going into the query?

Comment: Actually it could become a security problem if the wrong data is added to your DB (e.g. One could insert a script in the db that might get executed somewhere and at some point in your app). It could also cause errors.

Answer (score 1):

Kohana provides a db abstraction to different database types. Not all concrete databases might have prepared statements so they will get simulated. Some native escaping functions for specific databases might even be broken.

As you never know, it's always good to not only have one layer of security.

Another layer is that your script actually receives data that makes sense. E.g. a first-name string that is 8 megabyte large for example. Won't make sense regardless what the database is doing with it.